# Is there a way to store a custom object in a DataRow or DataColumn?

Tags: vb.net, object, datarow, datacolumn

Is there a way to store a custom object in a DataRow or DataColumn?

Basically I'm looking for the equivalent of a tag property for a DataRow or DataColumn. I looked into ExtendedProperties for the DataColumn but you can only store strings there.

```
drNewPathRow = dsOutputGrid.Tables("dtPathElements").Rows.Add()
   elm = pth.Elements(iElements)
   drNewPathRow(0) = elm.Name

    '  drNewPathRow.tag = elm .... I wish!
```

Comment: You could add a new column and store it there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
dt.Columns.Add("objCol", GetType(Object))
```

I didn't know I could do this.  Thanks the_lotus for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The *easy way* is to create a new column as suggested by [@the_lotus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/130611/the-lotus). But if you want to do it the *hard way* then you need to create a custom table by inheriting the [TypedTableBase(Of T)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358258(v=vs.110).aspx) class. You might need to override/overload/shadow more properties/methods then shown in the following example, however, it should get you started.

```
Public Class StorageTable
    Inherits TypedTableBase(Of StorageRow)

    Protected Overrides Function CreateInstance() As DataTable
        Return New StorageTable()
    End Function

    Protected Overrides Function NewRowFromBuilder(builder As DataRowBuilder) As DataRow
        Return New StorageRow(builder)
    End Function

    Protected Overrides Function GetRowType() As Type
        Return GetType(StorageRow)
    End Function

End Class

Public Class StorageRow
    Inherits DataRow

    Protected Friend Sub New(builder As DataRowBuilder)
        MyBase.New(builder)
    End Sub

    Public Property Tag() As Object

End Class
```

Simple test:

```
Using table As New StorageTable()
    table.Columns.Add("Column1", GetType(String))
    table.Rows.Add("value1")
    Dim row As StorageRow = DirectCast(table.Rows(0), StorageRow)
    row.Tag = "value2"
    Debug.WriteLine("Column1={0}, Tag={1}", row.Item(0), row.Tag)
End Using
```

Output:

> Column1=value1, Tag=value2